# shortening the function pop-up window

Tags: pycharm, popup, popupwindow

Too much information in the popup window of the method.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vdpf.png)

I can't find the settings to get it to look like the second picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3obAM.png)

Already check settings in Editor/General/Code compilation and Editor/Inlay Hints